# Complex Analysis - Proving a function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, maximum-principle

let:$\text{U}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ as $U$ open and path connected.
$f$ analytic in $U$ and does:
$\forall z_0\in U,\forall \epsilon >0,\exists z_1,z_2\in Ball_{\epsilon }\left(z_0\right)st:f\left(z_1\right)=f\left(z_2\right)$, prove $f$ is constant.

My try:
deduce in negative that $f$ is not constant, thus $z_1 \ne z_2$, and we will take the domain $Ball_\frac {\epsilon_0} 2(z_0)$.
$f(z)$ is analytic at that ball and at the closure of that ball, so according to the maximum principle, $f$ receives maximum at the boundary, which means:
$Max\left\{\left|f\left(z\right)\right|\right\}=f\left(z_p\right),\:as\:z\in \partial \left(Ball_{\frac{\epsilon }{2}}\left(z_0\right)\right)$, when $z_p$ is the maximum point.
without loss of generosity, $z_2>z_1$ and decide $z_2=z_p$, thus $z_p$ is maximum and it makes $f(z_p)=f(z_2)>f(z_1)$, in contradiction to the suggest that $f(z_2)=f(z_1)$
and then from the identity theorem, just "move" it up to $Ball_\epsilon(z_0)$
Now, I know this solution may have flaws, I am not sure of it since I assumed stuff that maybe are wrong ( probably using the exist and choosing if it is not allowed )  .
**If that proof is no good and I cant make it to work using that way, I will just try to understand my professor Answer, he has 2 solutions which are not understandable, but I will try my best to understand if needed**

Comment: In the statement, the existence of $z_1,z_2$ depends on $f,z_0,\epsilon$. We don't get to choose them.

Comment: You can start with an arbitrary $z_0$, and arbitrary $\epsilon_1>0$, and take $\epsilon>0$  so small, that for all $z_1,z_2\in B_\epsilon(z_0)$ you have $|\frac{f(z_1)-f(z_2)}{z_1-z_2}-f'(z_0)|<\epsilon_1$. In particular, for the $z_1,z_2$ that the statement of the problem says $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$, this would give $|f'(z_0)|<\epsilon_1$. Since $\epsilon_1$ was arbitrary, then $f'(z_0)=0$. This implies that $f$ is constant, since $U$ is open and connected.

Comment: ahh, the proof you did, is the exact proof the professor did, I did not understand how I can understand that expression of $f(z_1)$ and $f(z_2)$, with the $z_1 - z_2$

Comment: I mean, I dont know how to think of it, why it is true? I just dont see it.

Comment: Remember how derivative is defined.

Comment: Basically the derivative is $\lim _{z\to \:0}\left(\frac{f\left(z\right)-f\left(0\right)}{z}\right)=f'\left(0\right)$

Comment: I maybe understand what you are saying, if you take an epsilon, really small such that the distance between $z_2-z_1$-->$0$, so you can say that their image $f(z_i)$, is also small? why? and if yea, you can do say that it is derivative I guess ( That I kind of remember from Computer class actually, not calculus )

Comment: Oh Okay I understand that solution now actually. Thanks!!
About my proof, there isnt any way to make it work? without choosing like I did?